# How to use both localStorage and AsyncStorage for the nested objects?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I'm new to the redux-persist and I've stumbled upon a problem.

I have two reducers - favouriteArticlesReducer and readArticlesReducer

and their state schemas are the following:

*favouriteArticlesReducer*:

```
const initialState = {
    favouriteArticles: []
};
```

*readArticlesReducer*:

```
const initialState = {
    currentArticle: {
        isLoading: false,
        error: '',
        article: {
            articleId: '',
            header: '',
            text: '',
            imageUrl: '',
            originalUrl: '',
            categories: []
        }
    },
    readArticles: []
}
```

**My aim is** simple - I need to store **favouriteArticlesReducer.favouriteArticles** and **readArticlesReducer.readArticles** in the persistent store(i.e. AsyncStorage),

and to store **readArticlesReducer.currentArticle** in the local storage, so that after re-opening the application data for the current article will be removed.

I've tried to blacklist the current article object but it didn't help - the current article seems to be saved in the persistent storage.
Here is the full sample of the store configuration:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import favouriteArticlesReducer from './reducers/favouriteArticlesReducer';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import readArticlesReducer from './reducers/readArticlesReducer';

const rootPersistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const favouriteArticlesPersistConfig = {
    key: 'favouriteArticlesReducer',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const readArticlesPersistConfig = {
    key: 'readArticlesReducer',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    blacklist: ['currentArticle']
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    favouriteArticlesReducer: persistReducer(favouriteArticlesPersistConfig, favouriteArticlesReducer),
    readArticlesReducer: persistReducer(readArticlesPersistConfig, readArticlesReducer)
});

const persistedRootReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer);
export const store = createStore(persistedRootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found out that I just need to add `blacklist: ['readArticlesReducer']` to the `rootPersistConfig`:

```
const rootPersistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    blacklist: ['readArticlesReducer']
};
```